Converting konvajs state to Advanced SubStation Alpha (ASS) format for subtitles
I am building a subtitle editor using react.js. I plan to use konvajs to build the styling feature of editor like rotate subtitles, change size etc. How do I convert resultant konva state to ass format so that ffmpeg can render these subtitles on video.
If there is a better solution than using konvajs then please guide me.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Please let me know how you are maintaining the Konva state in react and any ref to the ass format to which you are trying to convert.
